# Programmatically determine if a word document is digitally signed

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, digital-signature

Is it possible to programatically determine if a Microsoft Word Document is digitally signed?  When uploading a document to SharePoint, we want to be able to update the document list item to determine if it was digitally signed.  Ideally, we would like to be able to query the document to determine WHO signed it.  We are not using a certificate authority like CoSign.

Answer (score 0):

[Please check this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/worddev/thread/8b020f91-acc5-4d33-a928-bf06bef8c6a9) to check the document is digitally signed or not.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can use some MS Word automation but this can be not an option on the server.

In code you can use [OfficeBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-office.php) package of our SecureBlackbox product to verify the signature of MS Office or OpenOffice/LibreOffice document and to extract, validate and check certificates used to make the signature. OfficeBlackbox is available in .NET, Java, VCL and Library editions of SecureBlackbox for any major development tool.